# Firebase - Add Value to Array which already exists

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add a value to an array in Firebase IF (!!) this value already exists in the array?

In the documentation I could only find the arrayUnion method, however, this checks if the value is already in the array and only adds it if this is not the case.

In particular, I have the following Flutter code:

```
Future logCount () async {
    return await collection.document(id).setData({
      'counts': FieldValue.arrayUnion([count]),
    });
  }
```

Do you know how to change this code or what I could use to not run into this problem with arrayUnion? I could not find something suitable in the documentation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the document and add your item to the array and update your remote document;

```
Future logCount() async {
  DocumentSnapshot ds = await collection.document(id).get();
  List counts = ds.data['counts'];
  counts.add(count);

  return await collection.document(id).updateData({'counts': counts});
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry for my late reply and thanks so much for your answer. I just got one question - how would this scale? If I understand the code correctly, you would download all the data in the collection, then add the entry and update the whole document. Would that not very much slow the code down as more and more entries are added to the collection?